# longblob to string by MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql, json, blob

I use code below to get `longblob` from `MySQL` database and put it to a `JSON` fromatted string.

```
$r = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

$result = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r)){
    array_push($result,array(
        'studentid'=>$row['studentid'],
        'start'=>$row['start'],
        'end'=>$row['end'],
        'startsig'=>$row['startsig'],
        'endsig'=>$row['endsig']
    ));
}

echo json_encode(array('users'=>$result));
```

Output is not the same as data is stored in database, so I cannot decode images with use of these strings.

in DB:

> OM0AV/+FyeCf+gjN/4Cyf4Vk6p8d/D1ruXTrC8vnHRmAiQ/icn/AMdqz/wozwl/z21L/v8Ar/8AE1pab8I/

in JSON string:

```
OM0AV\/+FyeCf+gjN\/4Cyf4Vk6p8d\/D1ruXTrC8vnHRmAiQ\/icn\/AMdqz\/wozwl\/z21L\/v8Ar\/8AE1pab8I\/
```

How should I prevent these escape characters near slash signes?

Comment: Both "in DB" and "in JSON string" are the same. So what is the problem exactly?

Comment: @sajushko : Sorry, I modified it. After submitting it show up the same. I pasted it now with code formatting.

Comment: What is your function to decode images?

Comment: @sajushko : I try to use this:
`byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(encodedImage, Base64.URL_SAFE);
Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);`
, but I discovered, there is something worng with escape characters in string, because every slash is replaced with `\/`.

Comment: Please paste whole javascript code to your question. Including the part where you loading JSON from your PHP script.

Comment: It is nearly full source code, only the sql query is missing form this PHP code.

Comment: Where is JavaScript which reads echoed JSON? I think the problem is on JavaScript side in reading JSON data. Data encoded to JSON format have to be escaped ( '/' replaced by '\/') becase if they not the JSON wont be valid. JavaScript function should decode that JSON.

Comment: @sajushko : I use up this variable in Java. Should I replace manually every \ with empty?

Comment: Java have to have a method equivalent to PHP json_decode which converts JSON to some kind of array. This function also should get rid of those escape characters. Are you using something like that?